# Neyman-Pearson Theorem Question

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

> Find the Neyman-Pearson test with size $\alpha$ to contrast
>   $$ H_0: \beta = 1$$
>   $$ H_1: \beta = \beta_1$$
>   with $\beta_1$ > 1 based in a sample of size 1 of the random variable with density:
>   $$f(x,\beta) = \beta x^{\beta-1}, \ \ 0<x<1 $$

I've found that the rejection region is

$$C = \{ x | \ \beta_1 x^{\beta_1-1} > k \} $$
I've been told that it's similar to 
$$C´ = \{ x | x < k´ \} $$ because C seems to decrease as x increase, but I don't understand why. Could you explain me why these two expressions are the same to solve the problem?

Comment: You have to figure out whether $\beta_1 x^{\beta_1-1}$ is increasing/decreasing in $x$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ and $\beta_1>1$.  Accordingly the critical region is expressed in terms of $x$ only.

Comment: Yes, but why decreases that expression for all x in (0,1)?

Comment: I don't think this is decreasing.

Comment: So why changes the sign > to < in the expression?

Answer (score 1):

The critical region you have found be NP Lemma,

$$\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)} \ge k$$
$$\implies x^{\beta_1-1} \ge k', \quad \beta_1 > 1$$
$$\implies x \ge k''$$

So we have that we'll reject $H_0$ if $x \ge k''$.

The second critical region you have shown is not correct.